# How to replace a string with an integer using mapping?

Tags: c++, dictionary

So the problem wants me to input a string, parse it for words (not removing punctuation) and then putting the words into a vector. Then, I need to replace words that appear more than once with a matching integer value, to sort of mimic the concept of file compression. It is specified that I must use dictionaries to stop the number mapping between words and integer. I'm just not sure how to replace a particular value in the map for some word from a vector or how I would write the code for that. For example, if I input "one two one two three two", I should get "one two 0 three 1".
Here's my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<string> getWords() {
  string word;
  vector<string> words;
  cin >> word;
  while (word != "$EOF$") {
    words.push_back(word);
    cin >> word;
  }
  return words;
}

int main() {
  map<string,int> abbr;
  string output = "";
  int next=0;
  vector<string> words = getWords();

  for (auto word:words) {
    if (abbr.find(word) == abbr.end()) {
      // put word to number mapping in map if new word
      // Output word if first time seen
      // Output number otherwise
    }
  }
  cout << output << endl;
}
```

Comment: The shown logic is unnecessarily convoluted. It's far simpler to construct both the vector and the map simultaneously. As each word is read it gets looked up in the map. If not found it gets added to the vector and the map. Otherwise its value in the map gets added to the vector, as a replacement. Doesn't that just ***sound*** trivially simple?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik  It does but this is how I am "supposed" to write it according to my professor and he's forbidden the class from messing with that. I just don't have a choice here, I need to figure it out ASAP for a test.

Comment: Unfortunately no one else on Stackoverflow could possibly know all of your instructor's minute details and requirements. And that, apparently, must be known, from the looks of it. Did your instructor explain how to convert an integer to a string? This must be done here, no matter what the actual logic is used. Which part of your instructor's explanation of this was unclear to you. There are multiple ways of converting integers to strings in C++. We can't possibly guess what your instructor expected you to use, here.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I think the idea here is to replace the map value for that vector value? There's really no actual instructions he gave us here except to note thru the comment where we should add code. We are not allowed to modify the rest. If you have any possible methods to complete this code, I'd really appreciate it

Comment: You're missing something, or you misunderstood something. The `if` statement will evaluate to true if the word does not exist in the map, yet. It is logically impossible to then replace the words in the vector, with the value in the map, because that must be done in the `else` part which does not exist. Your homework assignment either cannot be done, as described, or your understanding of the homework assignment is wrong. Pick one or the other. There are no other possibilities.